# how to calculate Sum for two different table with different containing table field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table "tbl_In_Details" and "tbl_Out_Details" 
Sample data for tbl_In_Details

```
ID  Item_Name   Rate    Quantity    Source_company  
1   wire         10        4        2020-04-21 22:47:29.083 
2   Tea          4         20       2020-04-21 22:47:52.823 

Sample data for tbl_Out_Details

ID  Item_Name   Quantity    Created_Date
1     wire        1       2020-04-21 22:48:48.233   
2     wire        2       2020-04-21 22:50:16.367   
3     Tea         2       2020-04-21 23:48:39.943
```

Now i want to calculate SUM of price and price (RATE*QUANTITY) from out going table
i tried in such a way but not getting result

```
select o.Item_Name, SUM(o.quantity) as Total_quantity ,SUM(o.quantity * i.Rate) as Expenses
from tbl_In_Details i inner join tbl_Out_Details o
ON i.Item_Name = o.Item_Name group  by o.Item_Name,o.quantity, i.Rate
```

My Output should be

```
Item_Name   Total_quantity  Expenses
Tea           2               8
wire          3               30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is completely fine. The only thing you need to get the desired result is to delete grouping by 'quantity' and 'rate'.

```
select o.Item_Name, SUM(o.quantity) as Total_quantity ,SUM(o.quantity * i.Rate) as Expenses
from tbl_In_Details i inner join tbl_Out_Details o
ON i.Item_Name = o.Item_Name group  by o.Item_Name;
```

Comment: thanks after converting quantity as int its coming as expected

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all` and `group by`:
Aggregate before joining:

```
select i.item_name, o.quantity, i.expenses
from (select id, item_name, sum(rate*quantity) as expenses
      from tbl_In_Details
      group by id, item_name
     ) i join
     (select id, item_name, sum(quantity) as quantity
      from tbl_Out_Details
      group by id, item_name
     ) o
     on i.id = o.id
```

Comment: as its showing sum operator not allow for nvarchar so i sum cast(quantity as int) as quantity but now its showing "Incorrect syntax near '('." where i need to modified

Comment: now its showing "Invalid column name 'id'." but id is there in both table then why its showing such error ???

Comment: @RAJEEVRANJAN . . . I left it out of the second subquery.